# Two Windows PCs intermittently lose LAN connection on home network while Linux machines and Wi-Fi devices stay connected

Tags: windows, networking, router, ethernet, connection

My home network has 4 computers connected via ethernet into my TP-Link Archer C5400X router (and about 22 devices connected via Wi-Fi at any given time). Two of the computers are running Windows 10 and 11, the other two are running Linux Mint and Raspbian OS.

My Windows computers (and only them) will often lose internet connectivity about once a day and only one weird trick seems to bring connectivity back. When they lose connectivity, they cannot ping the gateway. It started with just my one Windows 11 machine but then I added a Windows 10 PC to the network recently and it's been happening with that one as well.

So, the one weird trick that is **guaranteed** to restore connectivity to the Windows PCs every time is to boot up my Linux laptop which is also connected via LAN cable. As soon as that laptop boots up and is connected, then connectivity is restored to whichever Windows machines are running. And as long as that laptop is running and connected, I never lose connectivity on the Windows machines.

So it's got to be some kind of router issue right? Well, here's what I've tried with regard to the router:

- Factory reset both the router and the Netgear modem.
- Ensure that my router is not cloning the MAC address of another device.
- Ensure link aggregation is disabled.
- Consulted router system logs (only shows logs from 2019-12-23 even though I bought it new in 2021 and have since done a factory reset).
- Checked for router firmware upgrades (none available)
- Tested out a new, upgraded router. The TP-Link Archer AX10000. (Problem continued so I returned it).

The only custom setting I have on my router is a DHCP lease for the Windows 11 PC to have 192.168.0.100. I confirmed no other devices have that IP or have the same MAC somehow.

Before I figured out that my Linux laptop was this sort of guardian angel of the LAN connectivity, and before I added the 2nd Windows 10 PC to the network, I assumed the problem was some kind of software or hardware issue on my sole Windows 11 PC and I tried the following with it:

- Using a different network cable
- Changing to another LAN port on the router (this actually *sometimes* fixes it still)
- Reboot the computer (saw this fix it once)
- Upgrading RealTek LAN drivers
- Switching to a PCIe LAN card instead of using the onboard ethernet.
- Upgrading to Windows 11 (it was a Windows 10 PC and then I upgraded)
- Disable/re-enable the network device in "Network Connections" window.
- Ran network troubleshooter on the network device
- Ran "Network reset" which resets all network adapters to factory settings

But again, once I added another ethernet-connected Windows machine (entirely different brand/hardware) to the network and saw the same issue happen at the same time on that one, I kind of stopped thinking that there's a software/hardware issue with these particular machines. I've changed LAN ports around dozens of times so I don't think it's just "devices connected to ports 1 and 2 lose connectivity and the device connected to port 3 restores connectivity" or anything like that. It's specifically the Windows machines that lose connectivity and the Linux one that brings it back. No Wi-Fi devices in my house experience any problems.

There's 3 things I'm thinking now that I should explore:

- Factory reset the Windows 11 PC (less likely to fix everything and costly in time).
- Explore issues with firewalls on either computers or the router (all default settings currently).

  - Just tried disabling the firewall on one of the Windows computers but I still had the connectivity issue.
- Try a totally different router that's not made by TP-Link (my gut tells me this could be the way).

Another interesting tidbit is that I didn't have any problems like this with this router for the first year of owning it. Only started happening after moving into a new house (same ISP). Not sure why that would matter since it seems router related. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Switching the Linux laptop from ethernet to WiFi seems to have fixed the problem entirely. Windows PCs have no internet issues anymore. I have no idea why as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to something that I failed to mention in my original question: the LAN cable for the Dell Linux laptop is not connected directly to the laptop but rather through a Dell docking station, model no. WD19DC.

Plugging the laptop's LAN cable directly into the laptop instead of into its docking station has solved the issue.

While I can't articulate exactly why this happens from an in-depth networking standpoint, [a similar post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/43b5ko/laptop_docking_station_takes_down_entire_subnet/) said all that I needed to hear:

> The issue is that the docking station starts advertising the gateway's MAC Address.

It is mentioned that updating the USB3 drivers on the laptop will solve the problem. I haven't done a deep search but I have not yet found the correct drivers that are compatible with this Dell Precision 7540 and compatible with Ubuntu 20.04. The easier solution in the meantime is to plug the LAN cable into the laptop directly.